# Having trouble to create a third column in this HTML code. How to do this?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to edit a code that has on the left side an image and on the right side the text content. Below the text content there is a button. What I am trying to do using width=percentage is to create a third column where I will put the button into it and some other text.

I have posted my code into the jsFiddle for better understanding.

http://jsfiddle.net/cm9UC/

```
.blog-post {
margin-bottom: 40px;
padding-bottom: 40px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}
```

Better explanation

Suppose that now there are two columns. The first one is the picture, and the second is the text. What I want to do is to decrease the width of the text so that will let me to take the created space and make it a third column. The new column should have the button in it.

Comment: not clear what you want

Comment: @sanjeev Suppose that now there are two columns. The first one is the picture, and the second is the text. What I want to do is to decrease the width of the text so that will let me to take the created space and make it a third column. The new column should have the button in it.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is wrap the h2 and p in one div and wrap button in another div.
and define the width for them and use {float:left;} for each.

It will surely work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

[updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cm9UC/10/)

What I did is make your p into:

```
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
width: 80%
```

and then your a into:

```
width: auto;
vertical-align: middle;
```

can your vertical-align into top,middle, or bottom depends on your need.
like this you can change the column without making another div.

But of course the better work round is wrap them up with extra divs, that will be sleeker and  cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

I've just added 2 new line in your CSS and wrap the `h2` and `p` inside a `div`.

```
.post-type+ div{max-width:80%; display:inline-block;}
.post-type~ a{display:inline-block; border:1px solid red;vertical-align:bottom;}

margin-bottom: 40px;
padding-bottom: 40px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
overflow:hidden; /*new line added*/

}
```

Here is the working Demo. http://jsfiddle.net/cm9UC/60/